# Unable to bind DSE Spark Standalone Master to Public IP

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am unable to bind Standalone Spark Master on the public IP of an EC2 node.

I have tried setting SPARK_MASTER_IP & SPARK_LOCAL_IP in spark_env.sh to the Public IP.
I have also tried changing the broadcast_address and broadcast_rpc_address in cassandra.yaml.
However changing rpc_address, as suggested by some, results in

```
ERROR [main] 2016-01-12 18:27:59,542 DseDaemon.java:358 - Unable to start DSE server.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 54.183.171.210.
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.run(Server.java:198) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.969.jar:2.1.11.969]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:120) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.969.jar:2.1.11.969]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:492) [cassandra-all-2.1.11.969.jar:2.1.11.969]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.start(DseDaemon.java:353) ~[dse-core-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:575) [cassandra-all-2.1.11.969.jar:2.1.11.969]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:74) [dse-core-4.8.3.jar:4.8.3]
```

The port 7077 is of course accessible via Public IP but submitting a job  form the remote machine makes akka complain about dropping messages because it only wants to entertain requests coming in on the local IP.

```
ERROR [sparkMaster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-479] 2016-01-13 02:24:46,337 Slf4jLogger.scala:65 - dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@54.183.171.210:7077/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@54.183.171.210:7077] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.0.14.5:7077]
```

Wonder how can I go about having a publicly accessible Spark Master.

Comment: Following the discussion https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11570 I also tried changing SPARK_MASTER_HOSTNAME. It seems to be ignoring all of these environment variables.